# keep input boxes visible after form submission

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form with a show/hide input box element. When I submit the form the page refreshes
and it returns to default state with all but the first input box hidden. What I want is to keep all boxes that were show prior to submission still visible after submission. is this possible?

```
function show(id){

 if (document.getElementById(id+"-link").style.display=="none") {
    document.getElementById(id+"-link").style.display="block";
    document.getElementById(id+"-input").style.display="block";
  }
}

 <html>
  <form action='form.html' method='POST'>
    <table>
      <tr>
         <td><input type="text" id="a1" name="em_1"></td>
         <td><a href="#null" onclick="show('b1')">and</a></td>
      </tr><tr>
         <td><input type="text" id="b1-input" name="em_2" style="display:none"></td>
         <td><a href="#null" style="display:none" id="b1-link"
              onclick="show('c1')">and</a></td>   
       </tr><tr>
          <td><input type="text" id="c1-input" name="em_3" style="display:none"></td>
          <td><a href="#null" style="display:none" id="c1-link"
               onclick="show('d1')">and</a></td>
       </tr><tr>
       <tr>
          <td><input type='submit' name='submit'></td>
       </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</html>
```

Comment: You could add a cookie or adding a parameter to the value of action and each time the page is shown you check for it and hide or show input basing on that.

Comment: Umm... why are you hiding them then... can you describe your situation in more detail?

Comment: I'm hiding them until they have been cliked, but once they have been clicked they should be shown both before *and* after submission